# How do I change the background colour of my text?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the background colour of my text. What would be the best method to do this?

I have put the text into a div class and then referenced this to my CSS and added background-colour:xxxx;.

```css
.text {
  background-colour: #33383b;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 30px 30px;
  text-colour: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <p>
    <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Unfortunately this did not work, any tips to where I am going wrong? thanks

Comment: Have you used floats on the text within the `.text` div?

Comment: can u check if <p> tag inside `div.text` has background-color. since its occupying the content of the div it might be overlapping

Comment: mate its `color` not `colour`...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some corrections make your code better

- replace your `<p>` tag with `<span>` tag (because `<h4>` tag can't be inside a `<p>` tag).
- there is no exist any css property **background-colour**, use **background-color** instead
- there is not any css property **text-colour**,replace it with **color**

```css
.text {

    background-color:  #33383b;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 30px 30px;
    color: red;

    }
```

```html
<div class="text">
            <span>
            <h4>A.Willi A.G für Menschen zur Stelle</h4>
            Die A.Willi A.G ist als Personalverleiher in der gesamten Schweiz und im Ausland erfolgreich tatig mit über 
            30-jahrige Erfahrung in dieser Sparte.
            </span> 
            </div>
```

Comment: hey dream hunter, this seems like a good solution. gave it a try but no luck on my end. in the preview its blank, but on jfiddle you can see it until stretched. do you think there is some conflict in the css?

Comment: @bobmarley10203 I'm edited your code you given in question and it's working fine on the code snippet ,you can check that.

Comment: @i don't know who are the down voter and why?, please comment why you down voted,then i can improve my answer

Answer (score 2):

You're using the British spelling for "colour", use "color" instead.

Probably the easiest way to do this is to try wrapping the bits of text you want in a `span` or another element as follows, then adding `background-color` to that:

```css
span {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<span>Highlight text</span> Not Highlighted Text
```

Also, use `color: #000;`, not `text-color: #000;`. That property does not exit.

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a list of things that you should change to the code

- A heading (`h1` - `h6`) should never be inside a paragraph
- A `ü` isn't valid HTML; it's a special character that needs te be escaped with an ampersand, like this `&uuml;`, meaning *an u with an umlaut*
- `text-colour` should be spelled without `text-`
- `background-colour` and `text-colour` should be spelled without the `u`
- Then there's the padding of `30px 30px`, which you can shorten to just `30px`, but that isn't too big of a deal.

I don't like bashing other people's answers, but you've accepted dream hunter's answer, which is simply completely wrong in more than one way.

- The text you have there is obviously a paragraph, so changing it to a span that won't be semantically right
- Having a block element (such as the `h4`) inside an inline-block (such as a span) is wrong

Hope this helps

Comment: I wonder why this is getting downvoted... This is a solid answer

Comment: It even had 2 downvotes some time ago. I'm glad it's >= 0 now, so thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You set `background-colour` and `text-colour` for any css class for change background color.